# Why are expected_conditions all_of, none_of, and any_of absent in the Selenium python package?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with Python and came across the need to use `WebDriverWait` and [`selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) in it. I have to wait for an element to be removed and for another to be displayed, so I was wishing to use all_of and none_of to make the conditions easier to understand:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.all_of(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[title='VMC OIC-2 batch 2022'")),
        EC.none_of(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#startup")),
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#initial-startup"))
        )
    )
)
```

Unforunately, I received this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no attribute 'all_of'
```

On further inspection through raw printing I got to know that none of the any_of, all_of and none_of conditions were working.

Another thing to note is that the mentioned conditions *are* present in Selenium with Java. I could find [an issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7121) talking about this, and it seems like any_of, all_of and none_of were eventually added to expected_conditions as is evident in the Selenium repository's corresponding file: [expected_conditions.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/630f25fd269c9a437810bfd3a08b0bedcdd61248/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L367) (the last three functions).

This question is demanding an explanation, not an alternative, I am well aware I can write a function to do the same task or even copy the function listed in expected_conditions.py but I would really like to know why these functions are present in the repository and absent in the working package.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7
```

### install selenium 4 alpha version , there will be no new updates in selenium 3.141

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases

### you can see last update for v3 was on Dec 2018. click see new tags to see latest v4 releases

[image]

### the documentation is updated as per selenium 4

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/issues/627

Answer (score 3):

### expected_conditions.all_of(*expected_conditions)

[selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.all_of(*expected_conditions)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.all_of) is the expectation that all of multiple expected conditions is true. Equivalent to a logical `AND`. It is defined as:

```
def all_of(*expected_conditions):
    """ An expectation that all of multiple expected conditions is true.
    Equivalent to a logical 'AND'.
    Returns: When any ExpectedCondition is not met: False.
    When all ExpectedConditions are met: A List with each ExpectedCondition's return value. """
    def all_of_condition(driver):
    results = []
    for expected_condition in expected_conditions:
        try:
        result = expected_condition(driver)
        if not result:
            return False
        results.append(result)
        except WebDriverException:
        return False
    return results
    return all_of_condition
```

### An example

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.all_of(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[title='VMC OIC-2 batch 2022']")),
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#startup")),
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#initial-startup"))
))
```

---

### expected_conditions.any_of(*expected_conditions)

[selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.any_of(*expected_conditions)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.any_of) is the expectation that all of multiple expected conditions is true. Equivalent to a logical `AND`. It is defined as:

```
def any_of(*expected_conditions):
    """ An expectation that any of multiple expected conditions is true.
    Equivalent to a logical 'OR'.
    Returns results of the first matching condition, or False if none do. """
    def any_of_condition(driver):
    for expected_condition in expected_conditions:
        try:
        result = expected_condition(driver)
        if result:
            return result
        except WebDriverException:
        pass
    return False
    return any_of_condition
```

### An example

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.any_of(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[title='VMC OIC-2 batch 2022']")),
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#startup")),
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#initial-startup"))
))
```

---

### expected_conditions.none_of(*expected_conditions)

[selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.none_of(*expected_conditions)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.none_of) is the expectation that all of multiple expected conditions is true. Equivalent to a logical `AND`. It is defined as:

```
def none_of(*expected_conditions):
    """ An expectation that none of 1 or multiple expected conditions is true.
    Equivalent to a logical 'NOT-OR'.
    Returns a Boolean """
    def none_of_condition(driver):
    for expected_condition in expected_conditions:
        try:
        result = expected_condition(driver)
        if result:
            return False
        except WebDriverException:
        pass
    return True
    return none_of_condition
```

### An example

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.none of(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[title='VMC OIC-2 batch 2022']")),
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#startup")),
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#initial-startup"))
))
```

---

### Note

You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### This usecase

As per the [*CHANGELOGS*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/CHANGES) there was a fix to the `all_of()` function in *`Selenium 4.0 Alpha 3`*:

> - Fixing check of type of a returned element in a test for all_of condition

---

### Solution

Upgrade the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) python client version to recent [**Selenium 4.0 Beta 1**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/CHANGES)

Answer (score 0):

They have been introduced in this [commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/ef812996b41a633bbd8c71efdc891d5cd3615acc#diff-42621053a6328eeae47e9df4bcf1329a182b6241dcd1c7ee2900dfc187f9851c). While the version in [PyPi repository](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files) is 3.141 that commit will likely be delivered in 4.0.0 version.